# Why would I use int( input().strip() ) instead of just int( input() ) in Python?

Tags: python, string, int

If I want to take a number as input, would I also need the `.strip()` method? Like this:

```
n = int(input().strip())
```

Instead of just coding:

```
n = int(input())
```

I know `.strip()` returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string. But I wonder why / if it is necessary.

Comment: You’re right, there’s no need. Those will always have the same result.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int): "Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and **surrounded by whitespace**." (emphasis mine) Therefore as @Ryan says, there's no need to strip whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't necessary when you cast it to an integer with `int` because `int` already handles (ignores) leading and trailing whitespaces*:

```
>>> int('1 ')
1
>>> int(' 1')
1
>>> int(' 1\n\t')  # also handles other spaces like newlines or tabs
1
```

It's mostly important to strip the whitespaces if you use `sys.stdin.readline` (which contains a trailing newline character) and you don't know if the function that uses that value *can* handle additional whitespaces.

---

* Just FYI: The types `float`, `complex`, `fractions.Fraction`, and `decimal.Decimal` also ignore leading and trailing whitespaces so you don't need to `strip` the strings if you use any of those.

Comment: also `int` can parse things like `00001` where `a = 0001` fails

Comment: Yes, it can even parse the thousand separators, I was really amazed when `int('100_000')` worked (Python 3.6).

Comment: That's particularly useful with large hexadecimal numbers (using base 16).

Answer (score -1):

Now you can just use new library named ninput and use function named int_input()
for example

```
import ninput
n = ninput.int_input()
```

https://pypi.org/project/ninput/0.1.2/ there is library docs and files

Comment: If you want to promote your library that have been created today, you should add a note about that, to make clear to others that this is code that need to be tested